# Mapping List objects using lambdas and streams

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, mapping, java-stream

To start with, I have the following list of invoices. Each list object has a part number, a description, quantity and a price.

```
Invoice[] invoices = new Invoice[8];
invoices[0] = new Invoice("83","Electrische schuurmachine",7,57.98);
invoices[1] = new Invoice("24","Power zaag", 18, 99.99);
invoices[2] = new Invoice("7","Voor Hamer", 11, 21.50);
invoices[3] = new Invoice("77","Hamer", 76, 11.99);
invoices[4] = new Invoice("39","Gras maaier", 3, 79.50);
invoices[5] = new Invoice("68","Schroevendraaier", 16, 6.99);
invoices[6] = new Invoice("56","Decoupeer zaal", 21, 11.00);
invoices[7] = new Invoice("3","Moersleutel", 34, 7.50);

List<Invoice> list = Arrays.asList(invoices);
```

What's asked: Use lambdas and streams to map every Invoice on `PartDescription` and `Quantity`, sort by `Quantity` and show the results.

So what I do have now:

```
list.stream()
    .map(Invoice::getQuantity)
    .sorted()
    .forEach(System.out::println);
```

I mapped it on quantity and sorted it on quantity as well and I get below results:

```
3
7
11
16
18
21
34
76
```

But how do I map on `PartDescription` as well, so that's showed in my results in front of the shown quantities too? I can't do this:

```
list.stream()
    .map(Invoice::getPartDescription)
    .map(Invoice::getQuantity)
    .sorted()
    .forEach(System.out::println);
```

Comment: What is the output you are expecting?

Comment: What do you mean to say by *map every Invoice on PartDescription and Quantity*.. Is it that in output both these attributes should be visible while you sort only on quantity? Or its that you want to sort by both here?

Comment: @nullpointer: It's not 100% clear to me as well. I suppose that indeed both attributes need to be shown in the output and only sorted on quantity. But it's asked to use mapping for it. Otherwise Eran's solution seems to be the right one. I'm just wondering how involve the mapping part in his solution.

Comment: what is your expected output?

Answer (score 4):

You don't use `map`. You sort the original `Stream` of `Invoice`s, and then print whatever properties you wish.

```
list.stream()
    .sorted(Comparator.comparing(Invoice::getQuantity))
    .forEach(i -> System.out.println(i.getgetQuantity() + " " + i.getPartDescription()));
```

EDIT: If you want to sort by quantity * price:

```
list.stream()
    .sorted(Comparator.comparing(i -> i.getQuantity() * i.getPrice()))
    .forEach(i -> System.out.println(i.getgetQuantity() *  i.getPrice() + " " + i.getPartDescription()));
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Eran.
But now I'm wondering, now with your solution I have as output: partDescription quantity.
Let's say if I would like the following output: partDescription value.
(And value as in quantity*price, and also I'd like to sort by this value)
Could you help me out with that as well? I hope it will help to get more insight.

Comment: Thank you so much! I'll be trying to figure it out tomorrow step by step since it's getting late here, but it really starts to make sense now.